# SQLAlchemy event how to get delete items info after db session commit

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy event which is very very good, I can void a lots of repeated work.

Now I need to delete some items, and do some post work in `after_delete` listener after delete action, but, meanwhile in `after_delete` listener I need to using those **deleted items info** which cannot be accessed while the session had been committed, here's a piece of code .

```
def shop_delete_category(category_id):
    item_category = ItemCategory.query.get(category_id)

    if item_category is None:
        result['code'] = 100
    else:
        deleted_category_id_items = ItemCategory.query.filter(ItemCategory.id == category_id).with_entities(ItemCategory.id).all()

        # some other business logic

        db.session.delete(item_category)
        db.session.commit()
```

My event listener code:

```
@event.listens_for(ItemCategory, 'after_delete')
def after_delete_shop_category(mapper, connect, target):
    # business logic 
    shop_category_delete_signal.send(target)

    # here will need deleted_category_id_items
    # how can I pass in ?
    # logic will be like this
    redis_cache_delete_category_ids(deleted_category_id_items)
```

I want to do some post work after delete action , and in delete action I will use `deleted_category_id_items`, my question is

how can I pass deleted_category_id_items the event? Or is there some better way to slove the problem ?

Edit: My own answer

found : `before_delete` listener can solve the problem

Edit:
Another question how can I pass my own parameter to a listener, like this

```
@event.listens_for(ItemCategory, 'after_delete')
def after_delete_shop_category(mapper, connect, target, *my_own_paramters):
    # business logic 
    shop_category_delete_signal.send(target)

    # here will need deleted_category_id_items
    # how can I pass in ?
    # logic will be like this
    redis_cache_delete_category_ids(deleted_category_id_items)

    # can use my_own_paramters do some work
```

Thanks very much !

Comment: Very often you need to chain multiple events together to accomplish what you want. In your case, you'll probably want to have your `before_delete` handler set up an event for `after_commit`, so that deleting from your redis cache will only occur if the transaction actually commits and not if it's rolled back.